# Как изменить расстояние между значениями ординаты Х

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется такой результат, нужно что бы ордината Х была более разборчивой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте посмотреть в сторону `matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator`
(https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html)

и самому выставить кол-во значений на оси

вот тут примеры должны вам помочь

https://www.delftstack.com/howto/matplotlib/set-number-of-plot-ticks/